# Checking the value of column using the min date of other column

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have one table

```
  id     | guid | Status 
  ------ | -----| ----------
  1      | 123  | 2
  2      | 456  | 2 
  3      | 789  | 2
```

The other table as

```
 id.    | modified date           | Status 
 ------ | ----------------------- | ----------
 1      | 26-08-2017 04:05        | 0
 1      | 26-08-2017 10:50        | 0
 1      | 01-09-2017 02:03        | 0
 1      | 02-09-2017 13:43        | 2
 2      | 26-08-2017  03:04       | 0
 2      | 26-08-2017  11:04       | 2
 2      | 02-09-2017  18:03       | 2
 3      | 01-09-2017  03:45       | 0
 3      | 01-09-2017  12:04       | 0
 3      | 03-09-2017  17:08       | 2
```

In the first table whenever the value of status changes in that it will be logged in the other table.

I want those ids where the value of status  remains 0 when it was first saved(i.e min date for that transaction).

Id 1 got saved first time on 26th then the whole day its value remains 0(i have to check only first date).For id 2 on 26 it got saved as 0 then the same day changed to 2.So it will not come in this case.For id 3 also it remains 0 on its first date.

Required o/p will be 
id 
1
3

Comment: That sample data isn't readable in its current format. Could you try reformatting it?

Comment: can u help me with tha not able to do that

Comment: some comment was made

Answer (score 1):

You can use a query like below

```
select t1.id 
from table2 t1 
inner join
(
select id, 
min(modifieddate) over (partition by id) startDateTime,
max(Status) over (partition by id,cast(modifieddate as date)) maxStatusOnStartDay
from table2
)t2
on t1.id=t2.id and 
cast(t1.modifieddate as date)=cast(t2.startDateTime as date)
and t2.maxStatusOnStartDay=0
group by t1.id
```

<kbd>**[see live demo](http://rextester.com/TOKO82181)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
select id from (
    select id,
       CAST(modified_date as date) as [modified_date],
       [status],
       MIN(CAST(modified_date as date)) over (partition by id) as [first_saved]
    from TABLE_NAME
) as A where modified_date = first_saved
group by id
having SUM([status]) = 0
```